# Impact force of a pillow?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, power

My friend and I just had a discussion about how dangerous it would be to get hit in the face with a pillow thrown out of a train.
If we say the train is traveling at 100km/h and the pillows weight is about 1 kg. How would you go about calculating the force of impact and what would it be comparable to? Feel free to speculate on eg. slow down distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variation of the linear momentum can be linked to the force acting on the system:
\begin{equation*}
\Delta p = F \Delta t
\end{equation*}
So, if one assumes that the pillow stops completely in (this is a crucial point), let's say, $0.5\,s$, the force will be: 
\begin{equation*}
F= \frac{mv}{\Delta t} \approx 56\, N
\end{equation*}